# Does inject starting from 0 mean the same as sum

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-2.3

I'm new to ruby and was going though a piece of code

```
scope_value = {"tickets_scope"=>"1", "changes_scope"=>"8", "solutions_scope"=>"15"}
scope_value.values.map { |i| 2** i.to_i }.inject(0, :|)
```

I realised

```
scope_value.values.map {|i| 2** i.to_i }.sum
```

does the the same thing as well

In terms of functionality doesn't both lines of code do the same thing. Is there any advantage to using sum over the other in terms of performance.

Comment: `sum` was added in the version 2.4 of Ruby (Rails had it before), it was a common practice to use inject in that way.

Comment: Readers know what `scope_value.values` means, and that you will need to convert the values of the hash to integers with `to_i`, so your question could be improved by simplifying it to its essence: `scope_values = [1, 8, 15]; scope_values.map...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In terms of functionality doesn't both lines of code do the same thing.

Yes, these two snippets produce identical results.

> Does inject starting from 0 mean the same as sum

No, not at all. In fact, `0` is irrelevant here. You can omit it and still get the same result.

```
scope_value.values.map { |i| 2** i.to_i }.inject(:|)
```

Operations in these two snippets are very different. They only produce the same result because of special shape of your data. Which is "each number has only one bit set and no two numbers have the same bit set". Violate this rule and see results diverge.

---

BTW, before we had `.sum`, we used to emulate it with `.inject(:+)`. *This* does the same thing (when used on integer arrays)

Comment: @Sergio, you've been AWOL. Forgot not an edge case: `[].sum #=> 0; [].inject(:+) #=> nil`. We can say that `arr.sum` produces the same result as `arr.inject(0, :+)` so long as all elements of `arr` (if any) are numeric.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: sorry about that. New job, new place, not so much time :) Thanks for clarification 

Comment: @thebenman: same what it does outside of inject. When used on integers, it means [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR): https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-7C But as far as ruby is concerned, it's just a method. On arrays it means something else completely, for example.

Comment: @Sergio, non-numeric elements that respond to `:+` can be summed as well if `sum` is given its optional argument, an initial value. The doc [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sum) gives the example `["a", "b", "c"].sum("") #=> "abc"`. New city? New country?

Answer (score 1):

They *do* mean the same thing, but *only* because you don't use `Float`s and *only* because you don't have a `Range`.

At least in some versions of some Ruby implementations, `sum` has some optimizations and specializations that `inject` and `+` can't have because they are much more general. For example, in YARV, [the current implementation of the various variations of `sum` is almost 200 lines](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/enum.c#L3833-L4085), and includes the following optimizations

- [`Enumerable#sum`, when applied to an `Enumerable<Float>`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/enum.c#L3899-L3946), uses the *Kahan-Babuška* balancing compensated summation algorithm to prevent floating point accuracy errors from accumulating during the summation
- [`Range#sum`, when applied to a `Range<Integer>`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/enum.c#L3984-L4003) uses the well-known closed-form formula: `(end - start + 1) * (end + start) / 2` end is thus independent of the size of the range any only depends on the length of the numbers involved

The price we pay for this is that `sum` may ignore monkeypatched versions of `each` or `+`.